# Combine Ruby on Rails and AngularJS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, angular-material

Maybe this is a dumb question or even a common asked question (or just a lousy searcher). I want to start a new web application project using Ruby on Rails. On the other hand, I really like Angular JS with Angular Material for the form design. The have everything already implemented like an autocomplete, different types of buttons, etc.

Now the question is, how to combine those two? I want to use Ruby on Rails's routing, controller, models, resource etc. but Angular Material more for the Frontend Design and catch user's actions in events.

Answer (score 1):

You could place all of the AngularJS files in /app/assets.

Another good way is to create a repos with only the front-end part.

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look at this :)